# .htaccess with Unicode and normal English

Tags: htaccess, apache, unicode

I have the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^\x00-\x7F]+).*?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3  [B,L,QSA]
```

Which allows me to view the result of the following link:

```
example.com/Indian-Patriot-Name/104/8/ச்வடன்ற்யவீர்%20சவர்க்கார்%20రాష్ట్రీయ%20சமரக்
```

However, when I want to view the following URL (not unicode):

```
example.com/Indian-Patriot-Name/104/8/abcd
```

I am unable to view the output as I'm getting a "file not found" error! However, if I change the directive/regex to the following then I can read the above (non-unicode) URL properly.

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3  [L]
```

---

**Q.** How can I combine `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` and `([^\x00-\x7F]+)` in the same rewrite statement?

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^\x00-\x7F]+)+([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3  [B,L,QSA]
```

but I'm getting a "file not found" error again.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^\x00-\x7F]+ [A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3  [B,L,QSA]
```

But I get an Internal Server Error:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@sawarkar.in to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: As with all internal errors, check your logfiles, Apache will have tell you there what is wrong (besides the fact that it had searched for something to display as a 500 ErrorDocument and it was not found due to invalid configuration)

Comment: Also I do not understand your problem. You can not "combine" `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` and `([^\x00-\x7F]+)` as something matching the first specification can not match the second one (the characters in the first are indeed in the \x00-\x7F range that the second one want to exclude)

Comment: let me redefine this  rewrite ([^\x00-\x7F]+) works fine. How can I allow   A-Za-z0-9- too in  ([^\x00-\x7F]+)

Comment: Still not clear to me, but try `([^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Za-z0-9-]+)`

Comment: let me redefine this.  " rewrite ([^\x00-\x7F]+) " works fine for unicode only. I wan to allow   A-Za-z0-9- character set in this rewrite statement    i.e.Unicode and  A-Za-z0-9 together in same rewrite statement

Comment: Are the unicode character sets just letters, ideographs, and letters with accent marks?

Comment: Unicode will have mostly alphabets , numerical of Indian Language

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^\x00-\x7F]+ [A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3 [B,L,QSA]
> ```
>
> I get Internal Server Error ...

You have an erroneous *space* in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This will result in your "Internal Server Error" since *spaces* are delimiters in Apache directives. If you check your error log you'll probably see an error about "Invalid flags", since `indianpatriot.php?id...` will now be seen as the *flags* argument to the `RewriteRule` directive.

However, the suggestion by @PatrickMevzek in comments, to use *[alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)* looks as if it should have worked. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3 [B,L,QSA]
```

Note that your original regex that matches the unicode URL had an additional "catch everything else" pattern on the end: `.*?`. (Your regex that matches the non-unicode URL does not have this.) This does seem unusual. If this is required then you can simply omit the `$` (end of string anchor) from the end of the pattern to do the same thing.

Note also, that `[^\x00-\x7F]` is a *negated* character class, that matches any character *not* in the byte range `00`..`7F` (hex). In order to incorporate the latin alphabet, that falls in this range, then you could simply extend this range: `[\x00-\xFF]` - this is now a positive range that matches everything (which is no doubt more than you need, but you were probably matching more than you needed with the original regex).

However, this could perhaps be simplified. If you simply want to match *anything* (unicode or latin characters) at the end of the URL then `([^\x00-\x7F]+|[A-Za-z0-9-]+)` (or even `([\x00-\xFF]+)`) could be simplified to `([^/]+)` (ie. anything except a slash). And, providing you don't also mind matching the underscore character, then `[A-Za-z0-9-]` could be reduced to `[\w-]`. So, this becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^Indian-Patriot-Name-English/(\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([^/]+)?$ indianpatriot.php?id=$1&lid=$2&name=$3 [B,L,QSA]
```